# How do I put django cms plugins classes inside multiple files instead of just putting it all inside cms_plugins.py?

Tags: python, django, plugins, django-cms

So I have a project where I am using Django CMS as the root of my project. First of all I'm new to Django CMS, and I now want to code some plugins to put into my pages. I searched for the solution but everywhere it says that I should put it inside cms_plugins.py.

I tried creating a folder named **cms_plugins** and created an **__init__.py** file inside it. Then I created the plugin inside a file named **ThePlugin.py** and coded my plugin the same way I did it in **cms_plugins.py**. Unfortunately it's not working. If someone can help me I'd be really gratefull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! `cms_plugins` is used to autodiscover plugins. Hence, you have to import the plugins from the `__init__.py` file, e.g.,

```
from .ThePlugin import ThePlugin
```

Alternatively, you can have a `cms_plugin.py` file and import them from wherever you'd like to have them:

```
from my_plugin_collection.ux.general import ThePlugin
```